# Prompt gender code

Tags: java, oop

How to prompt for the gender until a valid gender ‘M’ or ‘F’ is entered?

I thought of using the static method for readGender.

```
public static void readGender(){

    }
```

Can somebody complete the coding?

Comment: I can. The question is can you? SO is not a code completion service

Comment: We will not do your homework for you.  What have you tried? What don't you understand? Are you asking how to read a string? Check equality? Write a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general algorithm is as follows:

```
Object gender;
do{
   //prompt for gender
while(gender is not valid);
//continue with program
```